# Images not showing in Safari and Internet

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that I am currently working on, and I while seeing it on my Ipad (IOS 9.3.5), I noticed that the images were not showing up. Instead I get the image not available icon. After I tried it on all the browsers I have on my computer (Brave, Chrome, Edge, and Internet Explorer), I found that the same problem occurred on Internet Explorer. I tried inspecting element and tinkering a bit, but was unable to find the problem. The console was empty. In the network tab though the status code for the images was 206 (Partial Content). The part that confuses me now is that there are other pages with images inserted in the same way (DOM manipulation), but they still show up? Here are the two pages:
Not Working: https://themuslimgarden.github.io/Videos
Working: https://themuslimgarden.github.io/Islamic%20History

Thank You. Here is the script that manipulates the DOM:

```
var d = document;
var Content = d.getElementById("content");
var previewBox = function(ImgURL, Title, Description, URL) {
    return "<a target='_blank' href='" + URL + "'><div class='previewBox'>    <img src='" + ImgURL + "' class='image'>    <h4 class='title-previewBox'>" + Title + "</h4><p class='description-previewBox'> " + Description + "</p></div></a>";
};
function drawBoxes(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Content.innerHTML += previewBox(array[i].imgSrc, array[i].name, array[i].description, array[i].URL);
    }
}
drawBoxes(array);
```

Here is a screen shot

[Website in internet explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fERc.png)

Comment: I can see all the images, can you provide a screenshot to showcase the problem you are facing.

Comment: You should also try to look at the network tab of the developper tools of the browser to check if the requests for the image are sent and what it answers when it bugs (and add details here)

Comment: @AhmadDalao: I added an image

Comment: @Kaddath: Here is what i got for one image: 

   Request URL: https://themuslimgarden.github.io/images/As%20Hab%20Al-Ukhdud%20Preview%20Image.png
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 206 /

Comment: You should add this detail to the question itself, it's interesting. I've never encountered a 206 code ("Partial Content") myself so I can't answer, but it can help others answer you

Comment: Maybe it is because of the image URL and how IE interpreter it? 

maybe you should change it a little bit just like that, `../images/yourimage.png` that might work.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it did not work.